# How can use C# to generate a script from jobs of SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-agent-job

I know that we can use SSMS to generate a script of the jobs of SQL Server.
Now I want do this by C#, how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smo: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms202375.aspx

Answer (score 1):

easy :

http://www.sqldbadiaries.com/2010/11/08/generate-script-of-all-jobs/

Comment: Thank you :) but as  I said, I know this